# Why is password type of AzureKeyVaultSecret dropped when creating LinkedService via powershell,

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I'm attemping to create a LinkedService via the powershell command

```
New-AzureRmDataFactoryV2LinkedService -ResourceGroupName rg -DataFactoryName df -Name n -DefinitionFile n.json
```

the result is that the LinkedService is created, however the reference to the password type of AzureKeyVaultSecret is removed rendering it non-operational

The config file n.json was extracted from the DataFactory code tab and has the syntax below...

```
{
"name": "<name>",
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
"properties": {
    "type": "Oracle",
    "typeProperties": {
        "connectionString": "host=<host>;port=<port>;serviceName=<serviceName>;user id=<user_id>",
        "password": {
            "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
            "store": {
                "referenceName": "Prod_KeyVault",
                "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
            },
            "secretName": "<secretname>"
        }
    },
    "connectVia": {
        "referenceName": "<runtimename>",
        "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
    }
}
```

}

When the new LinkedService is created, the code looks exactly the same except properties->typeProperties->password is removed and requires manual configuration - which I'm trying to avoid if possible.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have tried using "Update-Module -Name AzureRm.DataFactoryV2" to update your powershell to the latest version, and it is still the same behavior, then the possible root cause is that password is not support as Azure Key Value yet in Powershell. As far as I know, it is a new feature added recently. So it may take some time to rollout it to Powershell.

In that case, the workaround is to use UI to create linked service for now.

Comment: Thanks - that's a shame though - it defeats the CICD approach I wanted to use.